# Facebook Live Comments API: Missing 'user' info

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I'm encountering an issue with the Facebook Live Comments API. I have obtained the 'user_videos' permission, and I am able to retrieve comments. However, when it comes to comments from my friends, I can only see the comment content, and the 'user' field is missing, so I don't know who made the comment. I've read the Facebook documentation mentioning 'The Business Asset User Profile Access' feature to access comments made by others who are not the video creators. I'm still confused about how to proceed. I'd greatly appreciate guidance from those with experience in this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, this is typical.  I haven't used this API in years, but last time I did, I was not able to use the "live" version to get the user data.

Comment: If you requested the `user_videos` permission, then this must be about a video on a private profile(?) - so I don't think Business Asset User Profile Access would apply to begin with.